# How to optimize mongo aggregate query with date + count

Tags: mongodb, optimization

I have a query that takes around 10 seconds and looks like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { date: { $gt: before } } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$address",
      count: { $sum: 1 },
    }
  }
])
```

When I add an index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({date: 1, address: 1})
```

I expected it to improve performance but nothing changed.
I there anything else I can to to improve the time?

Would a timestamp perform better here than ISODate ?

Comment: Since you have an index on `date` already, converting it into `timestamp`, wouldn't make much difference. I think it's the grouping that's taking time, before `$group` doesn't use indexes.

Comment: See the [type comparison order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/), and similar [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38048124/does-mongodb-queries-a-record-by-datetime-quicker-than-by-string), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332975/mongodbs-isodate-vs-unix-timestamp).

Comment: @charchit - it really feels like the date match is the issue, If I remove that it's faster even though more records are affected

Comment: @turivishal does that mean converting dates to an int will be much faster? I don't really follow your comment

Comment: Ohh, if without filter it is fast, then matching is the issue, just verify it once, by running explain command like: `db.collection.aggregate(pipeline).explain("executionStats")`

Comment: I've decided mongo is a bad fit for this and I'm moving to a sql database. Thanks to all for the help.